# Do My Nintendo Just For You discounts stack?

Tags: my-nintendo

This morning, new Just For You offers have been added to the My Nintendo rewards in Europe. One game, Captain Toad: Treasure Tracker, got 2 Just For You offers. 20% for 600 platinum points and 40% off for 100 gold points. If I get them both, would they stack so I get 60% off?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [reward info](https://my.nintendo.com/rewards/b1e0fdd361b2f4f5), they don't stack:

> *The discount can not be used in conjunction with a coupon or another Just for You offer.